# Is it bad practice to cast a generic T1 to object, then to T2?

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I have a generic method in a base class similar to the following:

```
protected bool TryConvertTo<TIn, TOut>(TIn objIn, out TOut objOut)
    where TIn : MyObjectBase
    where TOut : MyObjectBase
{
    objOut = objIn is TOut ? (TOut) (object) objIn : default (TOut);
    return !ReferenceEquals(objOut, default (TOut));
}
```

Assume that I'm null-checking wherever necessary and handling any application exceptions accordingly. Is it bad practice to "double cast" objIn to object and then to TOut? If it is bad practice, are there any technical reasons why, or is it merely a reflection of an overall design issue?

I feel the usage is appropriate given my use case, but since I don't normally use such an expression, I thought it might be safe to get the community's opinion.

Comment: “I feel the usage is appropriate given my use case” What is your use case?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Given that you've constrained both of them to derive from a particular class (assuming `MyObjectBase` is indeed a class) why not just use:

```
protected bool TryConvertTo<TIn, TOut>(TIn objIn, out TOut objOut)
    where TIn : MyObjectBase
    where TOut : MyObjectBase
{
    objOut = objIn as TOut;
    return objOut != null;
}
```

(I'm assuming there are no custom conversion operators or `==` / `!=` overloads in `MyObjectBase`.)

On the other hand, this feels like a fairly strange thing to want to do in the first place... are you sure it's an appropriate design, leaving aside the implementation?

Comment: It really is/was an issue with the overall design...I had the team providing the interface fix their design instead. Doing the double-cast really shouldn't have been required. It's nice to know I wasn't crazy feeling that there was something not quite right. And you're right, "objOut = objIn as TOut`code" makes much more sense. For some reason I had a brain fart at 5:30AM, mistaking that as an unsafe cast. Thanks again!